# Python: unpack tuple in tuple

Tags: python, python-2.7, tuples, unpack

It is possible to unpack a tuple in a new tuple?

Something like this:

```
x = (1, 2)
y = (*x, 3) # This is not allowed
# print y should then give (1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: It's allowed in Python 3.5. Are you using Python 2?

Comment: Ah yes, my bad. I'm using 2.7.6. Good to know @KevinGuan

Comment: Why not `y = x + (3,)`.

Comment: Akavail's sample also works on python2.7 and up

Comment: Lol. Brainfart. Thanks @Akavall, interesting though that this is allowed in python 3. Apparently someone found it useful.